# Where is the "View-based Application" project type, in Xcode 4?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

Where can I find the "View based application" in Xcode 4, I'm using a Lynda tutorial, but they use < xCode 4, and I can't see it anywhere in Xcode 4.

Best Regards,

Comment: +1 for using the Xcode tag properly and relevantly. Very rare piece of diamond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xcode 4.2 it's under iOS then Application then Single View Application.

Comment: When more thing before I accept it Sir, why when I add a new view Controller, the I add a Label, I saved and I run it, I don't see any text?

Comment: I don't understand what you tell me.

Comment: @Uffo that should be another question.